# ASP.NET Progress bar display during Page transfer

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-ajax

I'm working on a website which handles large amounts of data. I have got a requirement to implement functionality to validate excel data uploaded by USER and show up the summary of results. I am currently  using two pages one for User Input and another for Summary.

This whole process is taking 30 seconds so i wanted to display a progress bar for user notification
while operation taking place .

****Question1 : If i dsiplay progress bar and do all background validation/operations in first page and later just show the results in seconds page What technique should i use(Sessions, cache object..) to pass data(collection object) from page to another. The Collection object can contain as many as 5000 and more records ****

****Question2 : How do i display a progress bar when user clicks a button on same page ****

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a 2-part MSDN Magazine series starting with the December 2011 issue, Dino Esposito wrote **A Context-Sensitive Progress Bar for ASP.NET MVC**.  This looks pretty comprehensive.  It might give you some ideas.

[Part 1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh580729.aspx)
[Part 2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh708746.aspx)